# Checking table data if has input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check my table data for empty field. I used `$('td:has(input)')` because all of my cell has `<input type="text" class="form-control">`. What I want to do if the user hit the **Save** button it will checked if all the textfield is empty otherwise it will prompt a message. But the user can fill one of the textfields but cannot be left blank. How can I achieve this?

Table:

```
<div class = "col-md-12">

    <table class = "table" id = "customFields">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Stock No.</th>
                <th>Unit</th>
                <th class = "description">Description</th>
                <th>Quantity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
                <td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>

    </table>

    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "addMore">+ Add</button>
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-danger" id = "removeRow">- Remove</button>
    <button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-primary" id = "save">Save</button>

</div>
```

Script:

```
<script>

    $(document).ready(function ()
    {
        $("#addMore").click(function ()
        {
            $("#customFields").append('<tr><td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td><td><input type="text" class="form-control"></td></tr>');
        });

        $("#removeRow").click(function()
        {   
            if ($('#customFields tbody tr').length== 1)
            {

                alert('Cannot be left blank');
            }
            else
            {
                $('#customFields tr:last').remove();
            }

        });

        $("#save").click(function ())
        {

            if ($('td:has(input)').text(function ()
            {

            }));

        });

    });


</script>
```

Comment: `$('td:has(input)')` means all cells that have `<input>` and nothing to do with user  changing anything. Question is confusing as to what exactly you are expecting

Comment: if you want to check for input you can have `if ($('td input').length > 0) {
 alert('Cannot be left blank');
}`

Comment: @guradio that only counts elements...it doesn't filter if they have value or not

Comment: @charlietfl Oh sorry for that. How can I checked this inside `$('td:has(input)')`?

Comment: @Francisunoxx edit question with full explanation of what your goal is. Not really sure what you are trying to do. Note that you are running that alert on page load also which is probably not what you want

Comment: @charlietfl yes it will only check it there is input and i think that is what OP wants although we need to wait for OP to clear that up

Comment: if you want to check if input value is not empty, just add required attribute to every input element. <input required>

Comment: `if ($('td input').val().length > 0) { alert('Cannot be left blank'); }` try this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through all elements with the `form-control` class and make sure their combined values length is greater than zero.

```
$("#save").click(function (){
    var values = "";
    $.each($(".form-control"), function(i, c){
        values = values + $(c).val().trim(); // .trim() to remove white-space
    });
    if(values.length > 0)
    {
        //Success!
    }
    else
    {
        // Error!  
    }
});
```

Comment: It says `c.val is not a function`

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry.  I've edited the answer.  `c` should have been used a selector for a new jQuery object and I've changed `c.val()` to `$(c).val()`.  Please see the updated code.

Comment: Hey this works. Can you explained me a little bit of this? I'm just confused in `function(i, c){
        values = values + $(c).val()`

Comment: This is the [jQuery.each() function](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).  

This function allows you to give it a selector, then run a function for each element selected.  The selector in this case is `.form-control` which means "grab all elements with the class `form-control` on them".  The actual callback function then has 2 variables available: the iterator and the element.  In this case, I just named them `i` (for iterator) and `c` (for control).

Comment: Yes I understand this part. I'm thinking what's the use of `i, c` in the function?

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to answering on StackOverflow and hit "enter" expecting a "new line" not a comment submission. :)

Comment: Oh I see hehe. Just hit the enter with shift :)

Comment: Yeah, I figured that out after the first time it happened. :)  

Thanks!

Comment: The variable `i` is the iterator for the `each` loop right? I'm just little bit confused why it called in the function. Why the variable `c` has been called here? `$(c).val().trim();` Sorry for newbie question.

Comment: This `function(i, c){}` is the callback function, so it's being called for every elements in the selector, `$(".form-control")` in this case.  `$(".form-control")` is returning an array of elements, so as we go through each one, the individual element we're currently iterating across is exposed as the second input of our callback function, in this case the `c` variable.  `c` is literally this current element in the array.

Comment: There are several other great examples on the [jquery.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) page.  For example, try this out: `$.each([ 52, 97 ], function( index, value ) {
  alert( index + ": " + value );
});`

Comment: That was a nice explanation! I already see what's the use of function of variable `c` here every time it iterates it's check the values right?

Comment: If I'm not wrong this example that you given is closely to key and value. Thanks for this!!